# Through "SELECT" Query show table data in form of "INSERT" Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `ABC` with columns `id` and `name`. I want to show all records in the form of `INSERT INTO ABC (id, name) values (1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2') etc.` with `SELECT` query. Is this possible?

Comment: To make sure you want to generate a list of statements, where each looks like: INSERT INTO ABC (id, name) values (int, string), right? Yes it easily possible with php and probably or simple mysql

Comment: SQL will give you an `OUTPUT` why you dont use that? Or do you need it in PHP or something?

Comment: Sorry meant to write: it is possible with php or simple mysql.

Comment: need to write a SQL query

Comment: Check your SQL client. Many GUI clients have such a feature built-in

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have command base interface for it, do command base has also? if yes can you please name any one?

Comment: Does your "command based interface" (whatever that is) have a manual? If yes, that should tell if it has such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("INSERT INTO ABC (id, name) VALUES (1,'", id, "'), 2, '", name, "')")
FROM ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it

```
select 'INSERT INTO ABC (id, name) values ('||id||','''||name||''');' from ABC
```

Comment: Will it work as what OP need? Read the question again.